# Difficulty figuring out an app/webpage to webpage interaction

Tags: javascript, php, android, json, parse-platform

**Context:**
The page I'm making should take in graph data from a JSON format from an outside application/webpage.  Queries to Parse.com will gather the initial data, so I can avoid setting up the graph page with a connection to the Parse database.

A webpage OR android application currently submits a request to the Parse system and get back a response formatted in JSON, then it must send that information to a webpage with graphing JavaScript for it to read and build the graph from.

I've explored the possibility of sessions or cookies, but it doesn't seem compatible with the android application end (unless webview can do something?).  GET looked like a good alternative originally but the size of some URI query strings would easily be too large.  POST, upon review, is impossible for me to use in this case.

**Question:**
Is there still another way to send this information **without** AJAX, PHP or some other server-side code?  Or would i need to scrap the idea as it stands, and just implement it all on the graph page anyway?

Comment: Can you expand on this: POST has more space for information, **but that method appears to be blocked.** Where are you seeing this limitation?

Comment: I would get a 405 error (Method not allowed)  I tried to find out more about why it was happening but it wasn't clear.

Comment: Ah I see. Believe that means the URL you're trying to post to doesn't accept the method. You might be stuck implementing it server side/on graph page then.